# Sign requests digital lu in ckyc api

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use ckyc search api for that we have to digital lu sign request using FI private key.

I am stuck on digitally sign request. 
I have dongle for that but i dot't have idea how we can digital lu sign a request.